Tikz-cd labels not appearing when using "to path"
I am trying to create a diagram where an arrow goes to the left, down, and to the right, as in the illustration below.

I'm using the "to path" function to make this work. However, I can't seem to get the label to appear. Here is my code.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
A
\arrow[d, "f"', to path={
    -- ([xshift=-1cm]\tikztostart.west)
    |- (\tikztotarget)}
]
\\
B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}

The diagram rendered by this code is the illustration I included above: the label "f" is missing. If I remove the "to path" section, then the arrow doesn't follow the path I want, but the "f" label appears. What's going on, and how can I make the label appear on this arrow?

You need to add \tikztonodes. Where do you want to put the label?

@JasperHabicht Where do I add that? I'm just starting out with these custom arrow paths, so I don't know much about how they work.

@JasperHabicht I'd like the label to be on the left side of the vertical part of the arrow.

https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#pgf./tikz/to:path

@Qrrbrbirlbel I appreciate the link, but I had tried to read it before asking the question and found it terribly confusing.

You need to add \tikztonodes to the to path declaration. Also, if you want to put the label on the left side, you need to change pos to 0.25.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
A
\arrow[d, "f"', to path={[pos=0.25]
    -- ([xshift=-1cm]\tikztostart.west)
    |- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}
]
\\
B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


With adding \tikztonodes after (\tikztotarget), you add something like node[pos=0.5] {<label text>} to the path declaration. Since you use an orthogonal connector, you need to change the pos value as 0.5 would be at the corner, wheras 0.25 is in the center between the start coordinate and the corner of the connector. Also see this answer.
